# shifting with a group by

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by, shift

I am currently working with a dataset where I am calculating transition times in an order process. The following data frame below...

Is there a way to get the shift to provide a null or 0 if a shift cannot be performed. I attempted the following code, but its shifting all numbers regardless of the OPTY_Number group.

```
Golden['TimeDiff'] = Golden.groupby("OPTY_NUMBER")
['TimeDiff'].shift(-1).fillna(0);

     Output im getting :
      OPTY_Number    Transitioned_By    Time_Diff
      13323344809     Ahmed             4539.0
      13323344809     Ahmed             91158.0
      13323344809     Chris             70096.0
      13323344809     James              257.0 
      87807651348     Rich               1354.0
```

Output I want:

```
   OPTY_Number    Transitioned_By    Time_Diff
   13323344809     Ahmed              4539.0
   13323344809     Ahmed              91158.0
   13323344809     Chris              70096.0   
   13323344809     James               0
   87807651348     Rich               257.0
   87807651348     Rich               1354.0
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could give us your input too.... just your buggy output is not going to help.

Comment: I cannot recreate your issue using random data. Output renders accordingly.